# Check if any value in array exists in csv

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, csv

I have the below code snippit

```
$dllCheckList = import-csv "c:\path\dllCheckList.csv" 
#dllCheckList.csv contains two items 'test1.dll' , 'test2.dll'

$resultsArray1 = @("test2.dll","test3.dll")
$resultsArray2 = @("test3.dll","test4.dll")
$resultsArray3 = @("test1.dll","test2.dll")
```

What sort of compare/loop would I use so that `$resultsArray1` writes `test2.dll`, `$resultsArray2` doesn't write anything, and `$resultsArray3` writes `test.dll, test2.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `Compare-Object <array1> <array2> -passthru -excludeDifferent -includeEqual`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a regular expression built on-the-fly from your csv data, then use that with -match against each of your arrays.  This saves iterating every array through every entry in the csv.  Not sure what your csv looks like, but you'll need to import it, and then build out an array of all the dll names first, or modify this to use the csv directly in place of the array.

```
#$dllCheckList = import-csv "c:\path\dllCheckList.csv" 
#dllCheckList.csv contains two items 'test1.dll' , 'test2.dll'

$dll_checklist = @('test1.dll','test2.dll')


$resultsArray1 = @("test2.dll","test3.dll")
$resultsArray2 = @("test3.dll","test4.dll")
$resultsArray3 = @("test1.dll","test2.dll")

[regex] $dll_regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($dll_checklist |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’

$resultsArray1,$resultsArray2,$resultsArray3 |
foreach {$_ -match $dll_regex}

test2.dll
test1.dll
test2.dll
```

An explanation of the line that's creating the regex can be found here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the output for `$resultsArray3` should be `test1.dll, test2.dll` rather than `test.dll, test2.dll` and also assuming that `c:\path\dllCheckList.csv` is an actual CSV with a header I'd use the `-contains` and `-join` operators:

```
PS C:\> $resultsArray1 = @("test2.dll","test3.dll")
PS C:\> $resultsArray2 = @("test3.dll","test4.dll")
PS C:\> $resultsArray3 = @("test1.dll","test2.dll")
PS C:\> cat 'C:\path\dllCheckList.csv'
Libs
test1.dll
test2.dll
PS C:\> $dllCheckList = Import-Csv 'C:\path\dllCheckList.csv' | % { $_.Libs }
PS C:\> $dllCheckList
test1.dll
test2.dll
PS C:\> ($resultsArray1 | ? { $dllCheckList -contains $_ }) -join ', '
test2.dll
PS C:\> ($resultsArray2 | ? { $dllCheckList -contains $_ }) -join ', '

PS C:\> ($resultsArray3 | ? { $dllCheckList -contains $_ }) -join ', '
test1.dll, test2.dll
```